# getting nouns and verbs from wordnet

Tags: java, nlp, wordnet

I'm struggling to find whether a word is noun or verb etc

I found the MIT Java Wordnet Interface 
there was a sample code like this, but when i use this i get error that Dictionary is abstract class and cannot be instantiated

```
public void testDictionary() throws IOException {


// construct the URL to the Wordnet dictionary directory

String wnhome = System.getenv("WNHOME");

String path = wnhome + File.separator + "dict";

URL url = new URL("file", null, path);

    // construct the dictionary object and open it

IDictionary dict = new Dictionary(url);

dict.open();


// look up first sense of the word "dog"

IIndexWord idxWord = dict.getIndexWord("dog", POS.NOUN);

IWordID wordID = idxWord.getWordIDs().get(0);

IWord word = dict.getWord(wordID);

System.out.println("Id = " + wordID);

System.out.println("Lemma = " + word.getLemma());

System.out.println("Gloss = " + word.getSynset().getGloss());

 }
```

i also got another java interface to wordnet

danbikel's interface

but i dont get answer for the query

```
WordNet wn=new WordNet("/usr/share/wordnet");
    Morphy m = new Morphy(wn);

    System.out.println(m.morphStr("search","NOUN").length);
```

Always the string length is 0, what is the correct arguments for this method? here is the javadoc of the method, what am i doing wrong?

```
public String[] morphStr(String origstr, String pos)
Tries several techniques on origstr to find possible base forms (lemmas).

Specified by:
morphStr in interface MorphyRemote
Parameters:
origstr - word or collocation, separated either by whitespace, '_' or '-', to find lemma of
pos - part of speech of origstr
Returns:
array of possible lemmas for origstr, possibly of length 0 if no lemmas could be found
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally recommend [Yawni](http://yawni.org), the new name for the old JWordNet project. To get all the parts-of-speech for a search word, you would call `FileBackedDictionary.synsets(yourQueryWord)`, then iterate through the returned `Synset`s calling `getPOS()`.

Comment: there are no links available to download the soyrce or jar file in the website.. can you please give me link?

Comment: The project is hosted on sourceforge at: http://sourceforge.net/projects/yawni/ . Get the source from: `git clone git://yawni.git.sourceforge.net/gitroot/yawni/yawni`. See also the Developers page: http://www.yawni.org/wiki/Main/Developers

Answer (score 0):

Have you solved your problem? I also used JWI before but the difference is that I declare my IDictionary variable as an static... but the rest it is almost the same. To get the nouns you have to iterate using:

> final Iterator
>   itr=dict.getIndexWordIterator(POS.NOUN)
>   While(itr.hasNext())...

Comment: yes i found the problem.. it was due to improper import.. there are 2 Dictionary classes, one in java.util and another in wordnet package, mismatch in import was the problem